# Ward identities for 1D integrals

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Some integrals of type

$$ I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~ e^{i(x^3/3 + a x)},$$

can be solved by realizing that they satisfy a differential equation 
like

$$ \left(a - d^2/da^2\right)I(a)=0,$$

and then we can solve the differential equation given some initial value. In this particular example, we have the usual Airy equation,
but the same can be done for more general integrands of the similar form.

My question is: is there a general way how to apply these methods for a case when I have a general polynomial in the integrand, 
i.e. something like

$$ I(a_1, \ldots, a_n) 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~ e^{a_1 x + \ldots +a_n x^n} ?$$

Whenever such integral is well defined it seems I can write a set of partial differential equations that determine it and it looks like I can do these things in a non-unique way. Is there a general theory that governs how to do these things systematically and optimally?

Comment: I'm also interested in your question and can unfortunately not answer it. But why is $(a - d^2/da^2)I(a)=0$? When I try to calculate it, I get $\int dx~(a - x^2)e^{i(x^3/3 + a x)},$ which equals to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx~(i\partial_x + 2a)e^{i(x^3/3 + a x)},$ which equals to $2aI(s) + i\left[e^{i(x^3/3 + a x)}\right]_{x=-\infty}^{+\infty},$ which to me doesn't seem like it converges, since—unlike $aI(a)$—the bracket depends on which values you choose for infinity...